# Concise way to write to console and file simultaneously?

Tags: fortran, windows-console

I'm trying to simplify the output of text of console programs.  Currently the programs are run in two different ways:

1. Directly from CMD or batch script
2. Remotely or blindly, called by another program

Thus, all information output to the user needs to go to both the console and to a default error file.

Currently, I'm just repeating myself:

```
write(*,*) "That wasn't a number!"
write(199,*) "That wasn't a number!"
```

The best I've come up with is using a subroutine:

```
subroutine werr(string)

  implicit none

  character*(*), intent(in) :: string

  write(*,*) string
  write(199,*) string

  return

end subroutine
```

Better, but still requires `call werr("Some text or another.")`

Is there any way to emulate the way write works, whereby I can simply have `werr("Some text or another.")`?

Comment: Is really the problem the `call` keyword? In other languages it is not necessary for subroutines/functions but due to the specifics of Fortran syntax it is required. You could make a macro `#define WERR(a)  call werr(a)` but it is hardly any better and it will be limited to the file where it is defined.

Comment: If macros are an option, `#define werr(x)  print *, x; write(199,*) x` could be an alternative way (where 199 may be an argument of macro also, plus the file may be redirected to /dev/null if unnecessary).

Comment: I'm not sure you need to print to *both* a file and the console. As I understand your question, you need to print to either one or the other, depending on the context. That is usually done either with a redirection, either with an option passed to the program. You then print to only one unit, which is either the console or a file.

Comment: If it either/or and you don't want to force redirection on the user you might look at using OUTPUT_UNIT in iso_fortran_env as the unit number - have a variable as the unit and set it to this or 199 as appropriate

Comment: Why not just print to standard output and pipe the output through 'tee' (which seems to be available on windows these days). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)